# Fetched data from Parse not saving in Array - Swift 2.0

Tags: arrays, xcode, swift, core-data, parse-platform

I am working with Parse and would like to download images for offline use. I understand that this is not possible with Local Datastore so I have decided to add them to Core Data.

I have successfully downloaded the PFFiles and put them in to an Array. I am then trying to create an Array for the NSData, but the Array count is always 0 when I use the code below

```
class DealsDownloadViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

var trailID = [Int]()
var trailStep = [Int]()
var dealNumber = [Int]()
var imageFile = [PFFile]()
var imagesArray = [UIImage]()
var imageDataArray = [NSData]()
var number = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

    let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext


    let dealsQuery = PFQuery(className: ("Deals"))
    dealsQuery.orderByAscending("TrailId")

    dealsQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
        if let objects = objects {

            for object in objects {


                self.trailID.append(object["TrailID"] as! Int)
                self.trailStep.append(object["TrailStep"] as! Int)
                self.dealNumber.append(object["dealNumber"] as! Int)
                self.imageFile.append(object["dealImage"] as! PFFile!)


            }

            for file in self.imageFile {

                let dealImage = file
                dealImage.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                    if error == nil {

                        let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                        self.imageDataArray.append(imageData!)
                        self.imagesArray.append(image!)

                    } else {print("error here")}

                })

                print(self.trailID.count)
                print(self.trailStep.count)
                print(self.dealNumber.count)
                print(self.imageDataArray.count)
                print(self.imagesArray.count)
            }





        } else {print("problem making arrays")}


        }

}
```

[image: Log from the original code]

If I move the Print statement up, I just get it printing every iteration of the loop.

```
for file in self.imageFile {

                let dealImage = file
                dealImage.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                    if error == nil {

                        let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                        self.imageDataArray.append(imageData!)
                        self.imagesArray.append(image!)

                    } else {print("error here")}

                    print(self.trailID.count)
                    print(self.trailStep.count)
                    print(self.dealNumber.count)
                    print(self.imageDataArray.count)
                    print(self.imagesArray.count)

                })


            }


        } else {print("problem making arrays")}


        }

}
```

[image: Log from second code]

In this case I can see that the data is added to both the imagesArray and imageDataArray.

This seems like such a simple issue but I am going crazy over it. What am I doing wrong, and is this the most efficient way of adding this data to Core Data? Am I overlooking something obvious?

I am new to programming so please do point out any mistakes I have made, and I am especially new as a questioner to stackoverflow (you have been indispensable while learning) so please let me know if you need any information that I have missed.

Thanks for your help.

**Update 1**

I have tried editing the code as explained in the comments and I am still getting the same result. I have moved the Print statement around on this code and it is still giving me the same results as above.

```
for file in self.imageFile {

                let dealImage = file

                dealImage.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                    if error == nil {

                        weak var aBlockSelf = self

                        let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                        aBlockSelf!.imageDataArray.append(imageData!)
                        self.imagesArray.append(image!)

                    }

                    print(self.trailID.count)
                    print(self.trailStep.count)
                    print(self.dealNumber.count)
                    print(self.imageDataArray.count)
                    print(self.imagesArray.count)

                })

            }

        } else {print("problem making arrays")}

    }

}
```

Am I missing something very simple? Thanks again for your help.

**Update 2**

This is the same code with (I think) the print statements moved outside of the For Loop. This is giving me counts of 9,9,9,0,0 from the print statements, whereas I think I should be expecting 9,9,9,9,9.

```
for file in self.imageFile {

                let dealImage = file

                dealImage.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                    if error == nil {

                        weak var aBlockSelf = self

                        let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                        aBlockSelf!.imageDataArray.append(imageData!)
                        self.imagesArray.append(image!)

                    }

                })

            }

            print(self.trailID.count)
            print(self.trailStep.count)
            print(self.dealNumber.count)
            print(self.imageDataArray.count)
            print(self.imagesArray.count)

        } else {print("problem making arrays")}

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no issue here!

You are being deceived by the way asynchronous block works. Asynchronous block gets queued up to get executed some point later in next run loop.

**Your first print statement is just after you pass the code to block which is yet to be executed.** Which is why you do see your image array empty.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I have read up a bit to try to better understand Asynchronous Blocks, but I can't work out how I can alter my code. Where should I move the print statement to? I have tried moving it all around the code but it never seems to give the 9,9,9,9,9 result that it should. Thanks again. I really appreciate your help as a newbie.

Comment: First of all, inside block, you should pass a weak reference to self object - like `weak var aBlockSelf = self`. And then calling it like `aBlockSelf.imageDataArray.append(imageData!)`. You should move your `print` statement just after `imagesArray` is set inside the block.

Comment: I still seem to be getting the same results from the print statement. I have updated my original question to add the change that you suggested, and I have moved both the print statements and the aBlockSelf variable around that part of the code, but it keeps giving me the same 9,9,9,0,0 or 9,9,9,0,0,9,9,9,1,1...etc result. Am I still missing something? Thanks

Comment: Results looks good to me as you are fetching images in for loop and passing block in for loop so your image count will get updated by 1.

Comment: But the problem I get is when I move the image count outside the for loop, the print statements give me 9,9,9,0,0, whereas shouldn't I expect 9,9,9,9,9?

Comment: I have just updated the original question again with the print statement outside the for loop. Thanks

Comment: No @JonBuckley - see you are updating the variable inside a block which you are not sure when it gets executed. Putting a statement just after the for loop will be executing earlier than block execution. You will have to wait for all blocks to get finished and then read the data. If I were you, I would have printed arrays on last iteration of for loop. I hope you got my point. Let me know if this is still not clear.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand now. That sounds like a great idea. Could you tell me how I can perform an action on the last iteration of the loop? I'm not sure how I would do that. Thank you so much for your help. This has been driving me crazy. I hope this is the end :)

Comment: :-). I'm installing Xcode 7.1 and its taking a little time. So, bear with me for not sharing the code. You can intialize an `Int` like `var counter = 0` just before the `for` loop, increment it inside the `for` loop. Then inside the condition `counter == self.imageFile.count` print the arrays. Can you accept this answer post that :)!

Comment: I think you've cracked it! Thanks a lot for your patience. I knew there must have been an easy answer. I think I need a bit more practice. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Always happy to help @JonBuckley. Cheers :)!

Comment: Hi again, I have run in to another problem a little further on. I was hoping you could take a quick look if you have the time (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33429044/loop-within-block-appending-to-array-in-the-wrong-order-swift-2-0). The elements of the imageDataArray are being added in the wrong order because of the block...but I am struggling to work out a solution to get them in the same order as the imageFiles array, so I can search within Core Data using trailStep and dealNumber. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks again.

Comment: I just suggested u a solution in that thread. Take a look. I would also advise you to prefill your image arrays with dummy data to avoid crash.

Comment: That is great. Thanks a lot. I will give it a try and let you know how I get on.